# Will search engines penalize my site if I reuse a paragraph from the frontpage on the subpage?

Tags: seo, google-search

My website's frontpage lists my various services with a synopsis for each. If I use that short synopsis as an introductory paragraph on the subpage for that service, would that be considered duplicate content? The subpage would have much more than just the synopsis on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is common among blogs and article websites. Duplicate content only becomes an issue when the majority, or all, of the content is duplicated between pages.